# If $f'(2) = 7$ , calculate the $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(2+3h)-f(2-5h)}{h}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> If $f'(2)=7$ then calculate the limit: $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2+3h)-f(2-5h)}{h}$ .

Okay, so I know what the definition of derivative is, but how do I use the fact that $f'(2) = 7$ to find that other limit?

Comment: Try rewriting the expression by adding and subtracting $f(2)$ on top, then break it up into two limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using definition of derivative,
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2+3h)-f(2-5h)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2+3h)-f(2)+f(2)-f(2-5h)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(3\frac{f(2+3h)-f(2)}{3h}-5\frac{f(2)-f(2-5h)}{-5h}\right)\\
&=3\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2+3h)-f(2)}{3h}+5\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2-5h)-f(2)}{-5h}\\
&=3f'(2)+5f'(2)\\
&=8f'(2)\\
&=8\cdot 7\\
&=56.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(2+ah)=f(2)+f'(2)ah + o(h)$ for $a\ne 0$, you find
that the limit is
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(2)(3h+5h)}{h}+o(1)=8f'(2)=56.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using (the simpler---see commments) L'Hospital's Rule and the fact that $f'(2)=7$ means that $F(h)=f(2+ch)$ is differentiable at $0$ with $F'(0)=cf'(2)$:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(2+3h)-f(2-5h)}{h}
%&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(2+3h)\cdot3-f'(2-5h)\cdot(-5)}{1}\\
&=\frac{3f'(2)+5f'(2)}{1}\\
&=56
\end{align}$$

Comment: How you get $f$ is differentiable ? Given $f$ is differentiable only at $x=2$.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729  The simpler proof of L'Hospital's Rule actually shows that $\lim_{x\to x}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$. It is an extension to bring that to the general L'Hospital's rule with $\lim_{x\to x}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. I'll remove my second stage to reflect this. But L'Hospital's Rule is indeed valid with differentiability at a point.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule#Special_case) is such a proof.

Answer (score 0):

By the mean value theorem
$$
=3f'(2+3h_1)+5f'(2-5h_1)
$$
for some $h_1$ between $0$ and $h$.

Try to find a similar argument for the case that $f'$ is not continuous.